# Xamarin Cross Platform Certificate pinning

Tags: ssl, mono, xamarin, ssl-certificate, pinning

I am designing an application using Xamarin and I want to boost our security by using certificate pinning. But I cannot find a way to do it. I can use the native approach for android to do it, but I want to know if there is a cross-platform solution to this, or even a solution for windows phone at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android and iOS you can use the standard .NET way with `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`.

On Windows Phone 8 you can use `StreamSocket`, call `UpgradeToSslAsync` after connecting and then read the certificate details.

On Windows Phone 8.1 you may also use

`var uri = new Uri("https://someuri.com/");
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
var certificate = httpResponseMessage.RequestMessage.TransportInformation.ServerCertificate;`

So not a cross platform solution...

[SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/editions.php#net) might be able to help with a cross platform solution, but I've only used it with Windows Phone 7.x a while ago.