# Securing Xamarin.Forms App traffic via SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, https, xamarin.forms

For my `Xamarin.Forms` application I've created a `ASP.NET Web API` as a backend to handle serverside stuff.

When it comes to security I'm pretty much lost.
I've read alot of articles containing alot of possibilities such as `HCMA`, `OAuth` and others.

For my purpose I think just `SSL/Https` will do the job.

I just have no idea where to start. All the documentation I've read didn't help me...

**Does anyone know a place where I can get some help or can anyone describe what to do to get this done ?**

**As far as I know I got to create a `SelfSignedCertificate`.
But where do I put it ? 
Inside of my App(Resources)?**

Please provide me some help.
Anything is highly appreciated.

---

**EDIT 1:**

As by now I have create a Custom Attribute `EnforceSSL` in my WebAPI.

All my WebRequests in my App are now `HttpsWebRequests`.

**Does this mean all my traffic is secured ?**

**As far as I could find out in order to secure my API/Website I need a `SSL-Certificate`. I can either create one or buy one ... (is this correct) ?**

I guess I need to inclued this in my `IIS`, where my `API` runs.

**Do I need any Client Certificate which I have to install on the phones which use my app ?**

Comment: Take a look at [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/), they make it pretty easy to add https to your server and I think it's free. If your app connects to a server that uses https your data is encrypted end-to-end and you don't need to install anything, just make sure your calls are to `https://server/ ` rather than http

Comment: thanks alot. I was waiting for some feetback so long :D

Comment: I know what its like to get the tumbleweed badge :( You'll need another certificate when you get your app into the store but thats a complete different headache.

Comment: You won't need to install the certificate on the app if you buy the certificate from a top level issuer. For example if you buy the cert from godaddy it will be trusted on your app automatically as they are a trusted issuer. If you create one yourself it isn't trusted and therefore you'd need to install it on every device that needs to connect. Much easier to pony up and buy the certificate. Or you can use my first suggestion which is a SSL middleman, which is what cloudflare is.

Comment: @TombMedia thanks for your help. I think I somehow got an idea. If you want to add your research as an answer and get the bounty feel free to do so :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>I dont want this to go unanswered, in future for general security questions http://security.stackexchange.com is the place.</sub>

> For my purpose I think just SSL/Https will do the job.

That's right use [HTTPS (HTTP Secure)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS). You can configure the webserver to redirect all http:// to https:// automatically. Follow this TechNet guide to [Configuring Server Certificates in IIS 7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc732230(v=ws.10).aspx).

I'd also recommend you test your web services out with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ that grades how secure your web site/service is. SSLLabs mainly catches [TLS 1.1 vulnerabilities](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57878/tls-v-1-1-vulnerabilities) so make sure you're on the latest TLS to get a Grade A. [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) is *basically* the same thing as SSL. SSL 3.0 was the last version of SSL. TLS – Transport Layer Security, a new name for SSL. TLS 1.0 is colloquially considered “SSL 3.1”. Created and maintained by Internet Engineering Task Force. The latest version is TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 is currently in draft format.

> All my WebRequests in my App are now HttpsWebRequests. Does this mean all my traffic is secured?

Nothing is 100% secure, but it sounds like you're following the recommended practices: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/http-stack/

> Do I need any Client Certificate which I have to install on the phones which use my app?

What you're thinking of is called [Certificate Pinning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466115/xamarin-cross-platform-certificate-pinning) and https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8743/self-signed-cert-using-httpclient

---

**The 3 most common mistakes to securing a mobile app are:**

1. Hardcoding keys into source code:

[image]

2. Not using encryption correctly:

[image]

3. Not using HTTP**S**.

---

Securing Mobile Apps is such a large subject - there are entire books on the topic. At the very least read up on: 
OWASP Mobile Security Project:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project and
Secure Coding Guidelines for iOS and Android: https://mgovlab.government.ae/uploads/SecureCodingGuidelines.pdf and make sure you've covered off the top 10 vulnerabilities:

1. Store local data securely
2. Protect remote data transportation
3. Implement appropriate authentication
4. Audit third-party code and services
5. Respect user data
6. Protect from reverse engineering
7. Secure web services and servers
8. Validate input and interprocess
   communications
9. Avoid exploitable code errors
10. Distribute an application securely

When you package your application follow the offical Xamarin guide, pay attention to ProGuard.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/

Comment: thank you so much for this answer. That helped me so much !