# Xamarin SSL/TLS Pinning with ServicePointManager

Tags: security, ssl, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We're developing a mobile application with Xamarin which will operate on Android and iOS initially, with plans to port to Windows phone in the future (if the 3 people who use it scream loud enough).

The nature of the data being transmitted and the actions that this application will allow (SSO into another read/write system) we want to take every step we can to secure the data transfer layer as much as possible.

Naturally this takes us down the path of SSL/TLS Certificate Pinning (in addition to other mitigations in the API calls themselves) to protect the clients from connecting to MITM proxies and the like.

We operate the API endpoint and have complete control of the certificates and thus we are comfortable with storing public keys in the app to pin to, as we will be able to update our certs and deploy with new pins in sufficient time. All certificates are valid 3rd party signed certs (not self signed).

Unfortunately it appears that doing the SSL Pinning with Xamarin is not performed very often, as we've found it difficult to find implemented examples.

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/) provide some [.NET sample SSL Pinning code](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#.Net) which uses ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback to provide a callback to check the SSL pin; but doesn't specifically mention it working under Xamarin.

Additional Google searches for this code often returns people using it to do the exact opposite of what we're wanting - they use it reduce the SSL certificate checking, not increase it!

[I can see one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27115310/1723275) which suggests this approach works OK Android and iOS - but I'm most interested in specific experiences in around using this in Xamarin, specifically Xamarin.Forms, to pin SSL/TLS Certificates.

Comment: My 2cent: Getting into x-plat public key pinning is a long answer (especially in global cloud-based load-balanced endpoints). The very short version of the approach we take is: On iOS use `TrustKit` for the `NSURLSession` and `NSURLConnection` connection delegates, on Android we use a `TrustManager` from the OS' `Keystore` to secure the `HttpsURLConnection` to only our global endpoints. We do not do WinPhone anymore. We do not use `HTTPClient` on Xamarin nor Xamarin's HTTPClient "native" provider approach on any platform for security-centric clients, much much longer story

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have validated that SSL/TLS Key Pinning works on Android (though only in an emulator at this point) using ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback

Comment: AFAIK that's working well with the default Mono HttpClient implementation, but not with `NSUrlSessionHandler` nor `AndroidClientHandler`. Which way did you go eventually?

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm not sure I understand the question. Why would we need to change? Do they work faster/better/more secure than the default?

Do they have a different TLS pinning implementation?

Comment: See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/transport-layer-security/ for more information.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're getting at now. Android is currently using AndroidClientHandler, and the TLS pinning implemented with ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback appears to work as expected - when running via the debugger it checks the certificates as expected.

Comment: On closer inspection it is called for one specific API call to an external service, but not for the main API calls.

Comment: My current point of view: ModernHttpClient enables pinning on both iOS and Android when configured correctly (via constructor parameter). And so does the default HttpClient of Mono, which just behaves as expected by using ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback. What I did not get to work is NsUrlSessionHandler. But I could add pinning to AndroidClientHandler: https://gist.github.com/aspnetde/8df8d0e6c02c3d847db1cd2a8823b208

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. 
I assume I need to set XA_HTTP_CLIENT_HANDLER_TYPE to whatever I call the extended class?

Comment: What I forgot to mention is a problem that occurs on Android with ModernHttpClient: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43188/modernhttpclient-not-throwing-java-net-exceptions-to-android-project That's the reason I am using my own AndroidClientHandler instead of ModernHttpClient. I don't know about XA_HTTP_CLIENT_HANDLER_TYPE, but in code it's just new HttpClient(Whatever_you_are_using);