# Dynamic certificate Pinning Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have been looking at a ways of doing dynamic certificate pinning to avoid publishing the app whenever a certificate is rotated or public key is changed.

Has anyone got any blog/github repo (ideally xamarin c#) on how to do it?

thanks

Comment: You can check this link which used the [ServicePointManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219615/xamarin-ssl-tls-pinning-with-servicepointmanager).

Comment: thanks but that is deprecated as far as I understand